# How to catch exceptions that are being thrown inside node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, node-modules, web3js

I want to catch the exceptions that are being thrown from inside node_modules in nodejs.

Example: I am getting exceptions from `truffle-hdwalletprovider` module

> Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

I can see that in console. But I want to listen to that exception in my `app.js`. I have tried keeping `try/catch` blocks wherever I am making calls but still I am unable to catch the exception. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use a debugger or manually add a temporary catch inside the modules code

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try to catch the error via below code :

```
const process = require('process');

// Event 'uncaughtException'
process.on('uncaughtException', (error, source) => {
   console.log(error)
   // write error handler
});
```